# How can i extract all the information from a web service?

Tags: java, web-services

I'm currently working with a little device that works to measure some stuff from electricity like voltage, power consumption and so more... and that device has a web service that i can get it by just writting the IP on my web browser and a panel is shown up... but it is limited i can't extract ALL the information from the device.

So, i created a CLIENT on java to make a connection directly to the server, and this is my code.
I need to mention that the protocol i'm using is ***Modbus TCP/IP***

```
import de.re.easymodbus.modbusclient.*;

public class run {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient("127.0.0.1",502);
        try
        {
            modbusClient.Connect();
            modbusClient.WriteSingleCoil(0, true);
            modbusClient.WriteSingleRegister(0, 1234);
            modbusClient.WriteMultipleRegisters(11, ModbusClient.ConvertFloatToTwoRegisters((float) 123.56));
            System.out.println(modbusClient.ReadCoils(0, 1)[0]);
            System.out.println(modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 1)[0]);
            System.out.println(ModbusClient.ConvertRegistersToFloat(modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(11, 2)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {       
        }   
    }
```

I made a connection, but how can i directly get all the information from the service once i'm connected to the service?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the service-provider provides you any rest endpoints?

Comment: No, it only gives me an IP